# Python: Is it bad form to raise exceptions within __init__?

Tags: python, exception

Is it considered bad form to raise exceptions within `__init__`? If so, then what is the accepted method of throwing an error when certain class variables are initialized as `None` or of an incorrect type?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Raising exceptions within `__init__()` is absolutely fine. There's no other good way to indicate an error condition within an initializer, and there are many hundreds of examples in the standard library where initializing an object can raise an exception.

The error class to raise, of course, is up to you. `ValueError` is best if the initializer was passed an invalid parameter.

Comment: The most used exceptions in constructor are `ValueError` and `TypeError`.

Comment: Just pointing out that `__init__` is not the constructor, its the intializer. You might want to edit the line *There's no other good way to indicate an error condition within a constructor,..*

Answer (score 38):

It's true that the only proper way to indicate an error in a constructor is raising an exception. That is why in C++ and in other object-oriented languages that have been designed with exception safety in mind, the destructor is not called if an exception is thrown in the constructor of an object (meaning that the initialization of the object is incomplete). This is often not the case in scripting languages, such as Python. For example, the following code throws an AttributeError if socket.connect() fails:

```
class NetworkInterface:
    def __init__(self, address)
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.connect(address)
        self.stream = self.socket.makefile()

    def __del__(self)
        self.stream.close()
        self.socket.close()
```

The reason is that the destructor of the incomplete object is called after the connection attempt has failed, before the stream attribute has been initialized. You shouldn't avoid throwing exceptions from constructors, I'm just saying that it's difficult to write fully exception safe code in Python. Some Python developers avoid using destructors altogether, but that's a matter of another debate.

Comment: This answer is really useful. It is not just speaking about the "green light", but mentions an example with the "destructor".

Comment: Your python code fails in its `__del__` because it is badly written. You'd have exactly the same problem if you did `this->p_socket->close()` in a destructor in C++. In C++, you wouldn't do that - you'd let the member object destroy itself. Do the same in python.

Comment: @Eric I wouldn't have the problem in C++ because [C++ doesn't destruct objects that haven't been properly initialized](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Exception_Handling#Constructors_and_destructors). Actually it's a very common idiom in C++ to [allocate resources in the constructor and deallocate them in the destructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). You suggest that the member object destroys itself (deallocating the resources in its destructor) - then the same issue arises when writing the member class.

Comment: Nowadays we avoid situations like this by using context managers.

Comment: @SeppoEnarvi It's a bit more subtle than that. C++ destructs subobjects that have been completely initialised, so if you had a class with three members, and the second one threw an exception, then the first one's destructor is still run. (Edit:) That includes base class subobjects, by the way.

Comment: `__del__` is also not really a destructor in the same sense as C++. There is no guarantee that it will be called when the object’s last reference goes away. (For example, when the interpreter is shutting down.) the proper way to ensure clean-up code is executed is to use a context manager.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see any reason that it should be bad form.

On the contrary, one of the things exceptions are known for doing well, as opposed to returning error codes, is that error codes usually **can't** be returned by constructors. So at least in languages like C++, raising exceptions is the only way to signal errors.

Comment: Not wrong, but this question is supposed to be Python-specific.

Answer (score 9):

The standard library says:

```
>>> f = file("notexisting.txt")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'notexisting.txt'
```

Also I don't really see any reason why it should be considered bad form.

Answer (score 4):

I should think it is the perfect case for the built-in `ValueError` exception.

Answer (score 4):

Raising errors from init is unavoidable in some cases, but doing too much work in init is a bad style. You should consider making a factory or a pseudo-factory - a simple classmethod that returns setted up object.

Answer (score 3):

I concur with all of the above.

There's really no other way to signal that something went wrong in the initialisation of an object other than raising an exception.

In most programs classes where the state of a class is wholly dependant on the inputs to that class we might expect some kind of ValueError or TypeError to be raised.

Classes with side-effects (e.g. one which does networking or graphics) might raise an error in init if (for example) the network device is unavailable or the canvas object cannot be written to. This sounds sensible to me because often you want to know about failure conditions as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do not raise exceptions in constructors invoked by context managers!

Example:
If `contextlib.closing` is used as such:

```
with closing(Foobar()) as foobar:
    foobar.my_method()
```

Then `foobar.close()` will **NOT** be called if an exception is raised in the objects constructor!