# Python: How to handle method calls on a class that could not initialize correctly?

Tags: python, oop, coding-style, module, refactoring

If an object relies on a module that is not included with Python (like win32api, gstreamer, gui toolkits, etc.), and a class/function/method from that module may fail, what should the object do?

Here's an example:

```
import guimodule  # Just an example; could be anything

class RandomWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.dialog = guimodule.Dialog()  # I might fail
        except: guimodule.DialogError:
            self.dialog = None  # This can't be right

    def update(self):
        self.dialog.prepare()
        self.dialog.paint()
        self.dialog.update()

    # ~30 more methods
```

This class would only be a tiny (and unnecessary, but useful) part of a bigger program.

Let's assume we have an imaginary module called `guimodule`, with a class called `Dialog`, that may fail to instantiate. If our `RandomWindow` class has say, 30 methods that manipulate this window, checking `if self.dialog is not None` will be a pain, and will slow down the program when implemented in constantly used methods (like the `update` method in the example above). Calling `.paint()` on a `NoneType` (when the `Dialog` fails to load) will raise an error, and making a dummy `Dialog` class with all of the original's methods and attributes would be absurd.

How can I modify my class to handle a failed creation of the `Dialog` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than creating an invalid object, you should have allowed the exception raised in `__init__` to propogate out so the error could be handled in an appropriate manner. Or you could have raised a different exception.

See also [Python: is it bad form to raise exceptions within __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507082/python-is-it-bad-form-to-raise-exceptions-within-init)

Comment: Why would this be any better/simpler than having the class handle errors internally?

Comment: @DK, it's simpler to know right off the bat that the object can't be used rather than fail on every single use of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to have two subclasses of it; one that uses that module and one that does not.  A "factory" method could determine which subclass was appropriate, and return an instance of that subclass.

By subclassing, you allow them to share code that is independent of whether that module is available.

Comment: The problem with this is that I would have to modify the dummy/subclass each time I modify the original (it would be annoying to keep them in sync).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that "checking if self.dialog is not None will be pain" but I don't agree that it will slow down things because if `self.dialog` existed it will be more slower. So forget about slowness for time being. so one way to handle is to create a MockDialog which does nothing on function calls e.g.

```
class RandomWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.dialog = guimodule.Dialog()  # I might fail
        except: guimodule.DialogError:
            self.dialog = DummyDialog() # create a placeholder

class DummyDialog(object):
    # either list all methods or override __getattr__ to create a mock object
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a dummy `Dialog` class is not as absurd as you might thing if you consider using Pythons `__getattr__` feature. This following dummy-implementation would completely fit your needs:

```
class DummyDialog:
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    def fct(*args, **kwargs):
      pass
    return fct
```

Comment: What if there are return methods?

Comment: You are right, Dialog-methods having return values cannot be mocked like this. Either you define them separately in the `DummyDialog` and return any dummy value, or you have to chose some complete different approach involving subclassing like proposed by Aaron.