# Handle exception in __init__

Tags: python, exception

Is it fine to raise an exception in `__init__` in python? I have this piece of code:

```
class VersionManager(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path
        if not os.path.exists(path): os.mkdir(path)
        myfunction(path)
```

The second line can potentially result in an exception. In that case the object will not be init'ed properly. Is there a better way to handle situations where code in `__init__` might throw an exception?

**EDIT**
Added a call to a function after `os.mkdir` 
Added a check to see if directory exists

Comment: Not only is the object not initialized properly, with no exception handler at best the caller of `VersionManager(path)` can hope catch the exception and have *no* instance, at all.

Comment: `os.mkdir` is a bit of a special case, because it throws an exception in a case that for many users is not an error -- when the directory already exists. So you might want to handle that case explicitly, aside from the question of whether your `__init__` function should raise exceptions in general.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that. However, I am more curious about a `OSError` which can be caused by a permission denied.

Comment: If `VersionManager` needs the directory to exist in order to work, and its `__init__` function fails to create the directory, then allowing the exception to propagate is entirely reasonable. The meaning of throwing an exception from `__init__` is, "I cannot make this object work, so I will not let you have the object". Or perhaps more formally, "I cannot establish the invariants for this object". Although again creating a file or directory a special case for a class invariant. There's usually nothing to stop some other process deleting it, so "the dir exists" is not a proper invariant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: is it bad form to raise exceptions within \_\_init\_\_?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507082/python-is-it-bad-form-to-raise-exceptions-within-init)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to raise an exception in `__init__`. You would then wrap the object initiation/creation call with `try/except` and react to the exception.

One potential odd result though is that `__del__` is run anyway:

```
class Demo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value=value
        if value==2:
            raise ValueError
    def __del__(self):
        print '__del__', self.value


d=Demo(1)     # successfully create an object here
d=22          # new int object labeled 'd'; old 'd' goes out of scope
              # '__del__ 1' is printed once a new name is put on old 'd'
              # since the object is deleted with no references
```

Now try with the value `2` that we are testing for:

```
Demo(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 11, in <module>
    Demo(2)           
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 5, in __init__
    raise ValueError
  ValueError
 __del__ 2 # But note that `__del__` is still run.
```

The creation of the object with value `2` raises a `ValueError` exception and show that `__del__` is still run to clean up the object.

Keep in mind that if you raise an exception during `__init__` your object will not get a name. (It will, however, be created and destroyed. Since `__del__` is paired with `__new__` it still gets called)

ie, just like this does not create `x`:

```
>>> x=1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Potential sneakier:

```
>>> x='Old X'
>>> x=1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>> x
'Old X'
```

Same thing if you catch an exception of `__init__`:

```
try:
    o=Demo(2)
except ValueError:
    print o          # name error -- 'o' never gets bound to the object...
                     # Worst still -- 'o' is its OLD value!
```

So don't try to refer to the incomplete object `o` -- it's gone out of scope by the time you get to `except`. And the name `o` is either nothing (i.e., `NameError` if you try to use it) or its old value.

So wrapping up (thanks to Steve Jessop for the [User Defined Exception](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) idea), you can wrap the creation of the object and catch the exception. Just figure out how to react appropriately to the OS error you are looking at.

So:

```
class ForbiddenTwoException(Exception): 
    pass

class Demo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value=value
        print 'trying to create with val:', value
        if value==2:
            raise ForbiddenTwoException
    def __del__(self):
        print '__del__', self.value

try:
    o=Demo(2)
except ForbiddenTwoException:
    print 'Doh! Cant create Demo with a "2"! Forbidden!!!'
    # with your example - react to being unusable to create a directory...
```

Prints:

```
trying to create with val: 2
Doh! Cant create Demo with a "2"! Forbidden!!!
__del__ 2
```

Comment: Note that if you want to avoid the "probably" when the error is handled, you can remove all doubt: `class ForbiddenTwoException(ValueError): pass`.

Comment: If you think of `__del__` as pairing with `__new__` (and `__init__` as just one function that might be invoked by `__new__`), it's not that surprising that it needs to be called.

Comment: @chepner: well, the C++ way is that the destructor is only executed if the constructor completes successfully. So if you think of it in the terms you say, then it's surprising or not according to what you think "pairing" should mean :-) For another example in Python, you might say that `__enter__` pairs with `__exit__`, but `__exit__` isn't called if `__enter__` throws. I think it's better to think that `__del__` pairs with `__new__`, and `__init__` is something that's called *after* `__new__`, not *by* it.

Comment: My point is, just because an exception is raised by `__init__`, doesn't mean `__init__` hasn't already done something that requires cleaning up. `__new__` *is* the constructor in Python, not `__init__` (semantically speaking; I'm aware that the Python docs refer to `__init__` as a constructor, but `__new__` actually constructs the object; `__init__` just sets some fields afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the call, as jramirez suggested:

```
try:
    ver = VersionManager(path)
except:
    raise
```

Or you can use a context manager:

```
class VersionManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #not-so-harmful code
        self.path = path

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            self.path = path
            os.mkdir(path)
            self.myfunction(path)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            print "The directory making has failed, the function hasn't been executed."
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
```

And to run it:

```
with VersionManager(my_path) as myVersionManager:
     #do things you want with myVersionManager
```

This way, you'll catch errors inside the `with` statement as well.

Comment: And `__exit__` won't get any exceptions raised in `__enter__`.

Comment: Yeah i think that's right -_-. That's why i also use a `try/except` block in the `__enter__` function.

Comment: What's the point of an `except` clause that does nothing other than re-raise the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/except when initializing the object.

```
try:

    ver = VersionManager(my_path)

except Exception as e:
    # raise e or handle error
    print e
```

Comment: And you'd need to tell the OP what happens to `ver` (e.g. it won't even exist)

Comment: You already did :), but thanks for the pointer on the deprecated `except`.

Comment: @SteveP.: little short on time to follow up properly

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is to simply output errors to console and march on:

```
import sys, os, traceback

class Myclass
    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path

        """Risky Code"""
        try:
            os.mkdir(path) 
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file = sys.stdout)
```

This way an exception will print out more like a warning rather than a real exception.

Comment: That sounds okay. But if another function needs the directory to be created, it will fail in the `except` case.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't apply to me. All my objects have some form of a status flag. So if the directory did not create it would automatically generate an error if you tried to call a function later on. I guess we have different programming styles. I thought the main issue was how to deal with exceptions in `__init__()`.